# Given $x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{c}{x_{n-1}}$, find the product of two successive terms $x_kx_{k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have the following nonlinear recurrence

> $$x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{c}{x_{n-1}}$$

where $c$ is a constant - and if it makes things easier, let's assume it's a positive integer - with initial conditions $x_1=2$ and $x_2=3$. I'm asked to find a product of consecutive terms in the sequence $x_kx_{k+1}$, namely $x_{50}x_{51}$. How can I approach this?

One thing that came to mind was to rewrite as $(x_{n+1}-x_n)x_{n-1}=c$. Then
$$\begin{cases}
(x_{n+1}-x_n)x_{n-1}=c\\
(x_n-x_{n-1})x_{n-2}=c
\end{cases}$$the idea being that I might be able to extract some explicit information about $x_nx_{n-1}$. Or perhaps to allow me to write $x_n$ in terms of products of consecutive terms.

Dividing one equation by the other gives
$$\frac{(x_{n+1}-x_n)x_{n-1}}{(x_n-x_{n-1})x_{n-2}}=1\implies x_{n+1}x_{n-1}-x_nx_{n-1}=x_nx_{n-2}-x_{n-1}x_{n-2}$$
I'm thinking the next step would be to introduce products, like something along the lines of
$$\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}x_{n-1}-x_nx_{n-1}&=x_{n+1}x_{n-1}-x_{n+1}x_n+x_{n+1}x_n-x_nx_{n-1}\\
&=-x_{n+1}(x_n-x_{n-1})+x_{n+1}x_n-x_nx_{n-1}
\end{align*}$$
but I'm not sure if there's any benefit to doing so.

Another manipulation that occurred to me would be to recursively expand the right side:
$$\begin{align*}
x_{n+1}&=\frac{c}{x_{n-1}}+x_n\\
&=c\left(\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}+\frac{1}{x_{n-2}}\right)+x_{n-1}\\
&=c\left(\frac{1}{x_{n-1}}+\frac{1}{x_{n-2}}+\frac{1}{x_{n-3}}\right)+x_{n-2}
\end{align*}$$
though I don't really know what this would accomplish.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119241/harmonacci-recurrence-and-identities-for-pi may help.